# Talend Position File Import - Only first field is getting read

Tags: etl, talend, fixed-width

I am new to this ETL tool but the flow is logical so following it fine so far. I have this raw data file which has data in fixed width columns. I entered all the details based on the file definition and everything seems to be working fine, except I could see only first column being read.

Here is what my positional file read job details look like:
[image]

The final output (just first column being read):
[image]

Here is what the flat file looks like:
[image]

Strangely, I can see all the records being read fine
[image]

Comment: Have you created all the columns in tFileInputPositional schema ?

Comment: Yes. Specified the formats/datatypes as well.

Comment: Is your first column of type String ? That error could mean Talend can't parse the data in the specified type

Comment: Yes the first column type is string. It's gonna be an alpha-numeric string. It just reads that fine. But doesn't go beyond that. Even the second column is string but it just halts after the first column. But reads all the records in the file.

Comment: I recreated the job with all columns being read as 'String' and it reads the file perfectly fine. The moment I try to read them in their respective datatypes (float, int etc), I get random errors. Like now the job is reading only the 5th column. All records are being read, however. The exit code 0 tells me that the process runs but this is isn't my expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the datatypes. For some reason, Talend wasn't throwing the correct error. I corrected the datatypes by matching them to the target schema and everything worked out fine.

Realized that all the float datatypes needed to be converted to BigDecimal. Mostly that fixed it.